# Выделение памяти для динамического массива внутри функции

Tags: c++, указатели, динамические-массивы

Допустим у меня есть код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int *foo(int n) {
    int *arr = (int *) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        arr[i] = i;
    }
    return arr;
}

int main() {
    int n = 0;  //Длина массива
    cin >> n;
    int *array = foo(n);
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << array[i] << " ";
    }
    free(array);
    return 0;
}
```

Эта программа создает массив и выводит его элементы на экран.

Можно ли выделить память для массива внутри функции и вернуть из неё адрес начала массива, но освободить память, используемую массивом, уже в функции main()? Или произойдёт утечка памяти?

Comment: Можно. Но если это не упраженение на `malloc/free` и ручную работу с памятью, нет смысла всем этим заниматься, когда есть `std::vector`.

Comment: Утечка, видимо, произойдёт только если забыть освободить эту память.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat возможно, что правильнее было убирать не метку [c], а плюсовые фичи, которые фактически используются только для вывода. Хотя первое, конечно, же проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Не очень понятно, почему вообще появилось сомнение, что выделение памяти и её освобождение в разных функциях может приводить к каким-то утечкам.

Собственно, подобным образом работают все классы (если речь всё же о C++), которые выделяют в конструкторе (условная функция №1) память в куче, и освобождают её в деструкторе (функция №2).

Если речь про C (на что намекает пара `malloc/free`), то так же не должно быть каких-либо сомнений с выделением в одной функции, и освобождением в другой. Главное, не потерять полученный при выделении указатель и использовать его в том же виде при освобождении. Ну и, конечно же, не допускать попытку повторного освобождения памяти, что является серьёзной ошибкой. В качестве защиты от такого практикуется обнуление указателя после освобождения памяти, т.к. вызов `free(NULL)` вполне легален и просто ничего не делает:

```
T* p = malloc(size);
...
free(p);
p = NULL;
```

Однако, в случае, если `p` передаётся по значению в функцию, где производится освобождение, обнуление будет лишено смысла, т.к. просто обнулится локальная переменная. Чтобы подобная защита продолжала работать надо передавать указатель на переменную, хранящую адрес выделенной памяти, т.е. "указатель на указатель".

Answer (score 1):

Да, так можно делать. Компилятор доволен, `valgrind` пишет что программа отлично работает:

> ```
> $ g++ -g -std=c++17 -pedantic -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion temp.cpp 
>
> $ echo 10 | valgrind ./a.out
> ==18731== Memcheck, a memory error detector
> ==18731== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
> ==18731== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
> ==18731== Command: ./a.out
> ==18731== 
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 ==18731== 
> ==18731== HEAP SUMMARY:
> ==18731==     in use at exit: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
> ==18731==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 3 frees, 77,864 bytes allocated
> ==18731== 
> ==18731== LEAK SUMMARY:
> ==18731==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==18731==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==18731==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==18731==    still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks
> ==18731==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
> ==18731== Rerun with --leak-check=full to see details of leaked memory
> ==18731== 
> ==18731== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
> ==18731== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
> ```

**P.S.** Не обращайте внимание на "still reachable: 72,704 bytes in 1 blocks". Это память выделенная стандартной библиотекой С++. Она есть даже если запускать программу с пустым `main`.